# Chrome Extension: how to store tab urls from multiple windows into an array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use `chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true}, function(windows)` to get the windows and tabs in the windows.

I am using a `2D array` to store the tab urls but I am not sure how to initialize it to the correct size in order to store all the windows and all the tab urls. I want the first array to store the current window number and the second array to store the tab urls of that window, such as:

`tabUrls = [window][tabs]`.

I am going to use:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows){
  windows.forEach(function(window){
    window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
      //collect all of the urls here, I will just log them instead
      console.log(tab.url);
    });
  });
});
```

but I am not sure how to store the information into a `2D array.`

Comment: `const tabUrls = windows.map(w => w.tabs.map(tab => tab.url))`

Comment: Thanks! How would I iterate through the map to access the urls? Would I use .forEach? I'm unfamiliar with maps.

Comment: The result of the map will be just a regular array, so you can use `forEach` there.